# Need script to replace TEXT in selected files

Tags: scripting, batch, sed

Environment
Windows 10,
C:\Folder_With_VMXfiles,
installed sed for windows

Tools: Batch script, sed for Windows

Requirements:

In folder C:\Folder_With_VMXfiles
Need to replace some text inside the vmx files  with another. 
But the replacing text is specific to every .vmx file.

Example:

- VMX file 1 has string "COM2" inside and want to replace it with "COM33"
- VMX file 2 has string "COM3" inside and want to replace with "COM34"

I tried to do with nested for loops but i could get the desired results. 
Basically i need to loop through the directory , select the ".vmx" files and use sed to replace text.

Tried:

```
@echo off

for /f %%i in ("Folder_With_VMXfiles") do ( 
    echo %%i
    for /l %%j in (1,1,9) do (
         sed -i "s/COM/COM%%j/" %%i )

 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell anything about the naming of the vmx files?
1.vmx, 2.vmx?
And why do you need a for when you know the names?

```
@Echo off
Pushd "X:\Folder\with\vmxfiles"
sed -i "s/COM2/COM33/" 1.vmx
sed -i "s/COM3/COM34/" 2.vmx
Popd
```

A dynamic approach assigning a COM port of two greater than the Clone number

```
@echo off
Pushd "Folder_With_VMXfiles"

for /l %%j in (2,1,9) do Call :sub %%j
Goto :Eof

:Sub
Echo Prcessing Clone%1.vmx
Set /A NewCom=%1 +2
Echo sed -i "s/COM\d+/COM%NewCom/" Clone%1.vmx
```

I don't know the maximal assignable com port number. To have sed actually change values remove the echo in the last line.

Comment: >>>     You don't tell anything about the naming of the vmx files?                          Name is Clone1.vmx to Clone9000.vmx                                                     >>> And why do you need a for when you know the names?                There are a lot of files, 9000.  Hoped to use for with sed and catch all of them .

Comment: @AdrianConstantinOprea How do you relate the ports to the files ?

Comment: COM33, COM34 were just examples.

Comment: @AdrianConstantinOprea Okay, but what in the for loop should be changed to what? You may even calculate with `set /A`

Comment: Numbering starts from COM3 .

Comment: all original vmx files have COM2 . need to change this starting from COM3 and ++   File 9 will have COM11

Comment: @AdrianConstantinOprea  Edited my answer with another batch.